# What data structure should I use to represent this board?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, unity-game-engine

[image]

```
 --- --- --- ---
| o | o | o | o |
 --- --- --- ---
| o | o | o | o |
 --- --- --- ---
| o | o | o | o |
 --- --- --- ---
| o | o | o | o |
 --- --- --- ---
```

Pieces go between the circles. The goal is to fill the entire board. I need a way to represent the board's contents. The pieces can be rotated and flipped. I tried using a matrix but that didn't work out very well.

Edit: Example pieces:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Depends on the pieces and on the type of methods you need to perform on the data structure.

Comment: "The pieces can be rotated and flipped." How do the individual pieces look? Why didn't matrix work?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I added a few examples.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I added  few examples. The matrix didn't work because I tried to group a column with a  row which represents it nicely but when the matrix is rotated it no longer represents the piece.

For example: The 2nd piece would be

`0 0 1 1 1`,
`0 1 0 0 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the board is so tiny, one way to approach this problem would be to represent the board as a list of piece+placement pairs.

Think of each *piece* as a sequence of drawing commands in [turtle graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics):

- `D` for "draw"
- `R` for "turn right"
- `L` for "turn left"
- `T` for "turn around".

The pieces from your post would be represented like this:

```
D-L-D-R-D-T-D-R-D
D-L-D-R-D-R-D
D-L-D-T-D-L-D-T-D-L-D
```

A *placement* of a piece adds information about the starting point for the piece, starting direction of the turtle, and whether or not the piece has been flipped, in which case the turtle needs to replace right turns with left turns, and vice versa.

Given a list of individual piece+placement pairs it is easy to verify that they do not intersect by "drawing" them on a temporary board. It is also easy to verify that a list of piece+placement pairs covers the entire board by "drawing" all pieces, and checking for empty spaces between the cells.

Comment: I've decided to go with a similar but not exact solution to this. I'll use a 3D array to store the array of 2D arrays for each rotation and flip of the piece (8 in total). A rotation increases the index of the current index by 1 and a flip by 4 (modding by 8 of course). It's as hard-coded as I'm comfortable going.

Answer (score 4):

I think a matrix would work OK, but you need to be careful how you fit the pieces together. Here's an illustration of how the pieces shown above might fit into a 3×3 puzzle:

[image: puzzle pieces represented as combinations of quadrant arcs]

I've coloured the circles alternately yellow and blue in a checker-board fashion, but you should actually consider each circle as a set of four quadrants so you'll need a 6×6 matrix in this case. The puzzle pieces can then be represented as 8-connected collections of cells that follow the colouring of the cells where they are placed, but have the ability to flip between blue and yellow (e.g., the "diamond" piece is coloured `Y B / B Y` as shown, but would flip to `B Y / Y B` if you moved it to the next gap below):

```
         Y Y B B Y Y
         Y Y B B Y Y    Diamond:  Moustache:   Snake:
         B B Y Y B B
         B B Y Y B B      Y B          Y         Y Y
         Y Y B B Y Y      B Y          B       B
         Y Y B B Y Y                 Y
```

So this is what your matrix would look like with these pieces added to it. You can see that the "moustache" and "snake" pieces have the same shape, but are coloured differently:

[image: same pieces represented as blocks]

It should then be quite straightforward to solve the puzzle by using a [constraint satisfaction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem).

Answer (score 1):

I can see some resemblance between your problem and the [Exact Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover).

In particular, Scott's Pentomino Problem as discussed in detail in one of [Donald Knuth's seminal papers](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/preprints.html): [Dancing Links](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/papers/dancing-color.ps.gz) (links to compressed PostScript format... you know the guy). The data structure used in that paper is a four-way linked representation of the Exact Cover Problem.

The Scott's Pentomino Problem looks like this (notice that the four locations in the middle are empty):

[image: Scott's Pentomino Problem]

and was solved by first describing it in terms of an Exact Cover Problem.

Essentially Knuth defined a matrix with 72 columns: one for each of the 12 pentominoes, and one for each of the 60 cells of the board minus the four in the center.

Then he constructed all possible rows for that matrix with a one (`1`) in the column corresponding to the piece, and a `1` in each column occupied by the piece; there are 1568 rows for the pentomino presented in the figure.

Once he had that matrix representation, he solved the exact cover problem on that sparse matrix using his Algorithm X (dancing links).

Of course, there are many more details in the paper.

This is an image of the Welded Tetrasticks Problem also addressed in the paper.

[image: Welded Tetrasticks Problem by Donald Knuth]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [graph](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/introduction-to-graphs-and-their-data-structures-section-1/#graphs); although, the example uses flight paths it is still useful in that each position (node in the graph) can have multiple connected nodes, which is what the question in this post describes.  Checking to see if the game board is full would be just a matter of ensuring that every position (node in the graph) on the board is connected to every other position (node in the graph).  Each board piece could span across multiple board positions and thus connect those nodes in the graph.